# How do I use Chrome DevTools to remove the script that adds "promoted" labels to LinkedIn job postings?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, linkedin-api

LinkedIn.com has a script on their website that hides how long ago a job listing was posted and replaces it with a "Promoted" label.

Can someone help me pinpoint that script in Chrome DevTools so I stop that script and see how long ago a job listing was actually posted?

[image: Example of Promoted LinkedIn job]

[image: Example of LinkedIn job listing with time posted]

I've tried fiddling around in the Network tab to see if I could hunt down the script, but had no luck.